# How to make <v-otp-input> field to hide in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Reference from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@bachdgvn/vue-otp-input

```js
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
 
  methods: {
    handleOnComplete(value) {
      console.log('OTP completed: ', value);
    },
    handleOnChange(value) {
      console.log('OTP changed: ', value);
    },
    handleClearInput() {
      this.$refs.otpInput.clearInput();
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row;">
    <v-otp-input
      ref="otpInput"
      input-classes="otp-input"
      separator="-"
      :num-inputs="4"
      :should-auto-focus="true"
      :is-input-num="true"
      @on-change="handleOnChange"
      @on-complete="handleOnComplete"
    />
 
    <button @click="handleClearInput()">Clear Input</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

i have otp input field, when i try to enter any number in otp field, i am able see the content inside of otp fields, But i want to make it hide as password(*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to "hide" the user input behind `*` characters you need to change the input "type" attribute. A quick look into the documentation for the package you provided showed it can receive a prop `input-type`. If you pass "password" to this prop it should display the entered digits as `*` characters.

Like so:

```html
    <v-otp-input
      ref="otpInput"
      input-classes="otp-input"
      separator="-"
      :num-inputs="4"
      :should-auto-focus="true"
      :is-input-num="true"
      input-type="password" // add this prop
      @on-change="handleOnChange"
      @on-complete="handleOnComplete"
    />
```